# HREF + ID CLICK COMBINATION

Tags: javascript, href

lets say i have 100 links like (every link has its own id):

```
    <a  target="_blank" href="/gallery/test-test-test/index.html" 
id="<?php echo $string = base64_encode('5x80x380055'); ?>" ></a>
```

how can i combine every
 `href + ?php echo $string = base64_decode('NXg4MHgzODAwNTU='); ?>` on click?

where `NXg4MHgzODAwNTU=` is the result of the string above

like the user will be redirected to http://domain.com/gallery/test-test-test/index.html?5x80x380055 when he clicks the link but on the html page it will show the result of the encoding like NXg4MHgzODAwNTU= ?

Comment: Please read up on HTTP  This is the first base - The bit after ? is the parameter to a get script#

Comment: Why don't you put the whole thing in href?

Comment: Please reword your question. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `atob('NXg4MHgzODAwNTU=')` in JS to decode your string to `5x80x380055`. So just concat that to the href and `?`.

```
el.href = el.href + "?" + atob(el.id); // el is your anchor element
```

You also have missed `<` in you opening PHP tag and `>` in your closing anchor tag.

Comment: i know, as it is not possible to post <?php ; so how should the whole javascript look like? lets say if i have 100 differint links? thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Ok, since it's not the issue in your code, I've fixed it in your question (no reason you couldn't write `<?php`).

Comment: You're welcome! The full code would imply iterating over all 100 link items, and changing the href. Or, if you don't want to modify href for all (I'm not sure why don't do it in PHP though), you can set up listeners for every anchor, and upon clicking it first change href using the code I gave you, and then open it.

Comment: could you post the whole javascript? :)

Comment: right now im using this one <script>
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
 if(nodeList[i].id!='' && nodeList[i].id.substr(0,4)=='GOLD')
  nodeList[i].onclick=function() { this.href=this.href+'?'+this.id.substr(4); this.onclick=function(){}};
</script> but without out the 64base encode is just lest say: id="GOLD5x1x230115" ..

Comment: Seems like you can just change `this.href=this.href+'?'+this.id.substr(4);` into `this.href=this.href+'?'+ atob(this.id);`

Comment: ok just tried but between ? and 5x1x230115 i get %18%E2%C3 strange?

Comment: Ah, it's because of that GOLD thing... `this.href=this.href+'?'+ atob(this.id.substr(4));`